# what is the formula of increasing the brightness of a bitmap?

Tags: c++

what is the formula of increasing the brightness of a bitmap? i m working in MFC

Answer (score 3):

In broad terms, one method is to convert the RGB value each pixel to a different model like [HSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV), make the brightness adjustment, then convert it back to RGB

Practically speaking, check out this [CBitmapEx](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/CBitmapEx.aspx) class from The Code Project.

Comment: is there any other easy method? i have heard that it can be done by averaging color pixels. like bw=(r+g+b)/3 but where  should we place this bw in this dc.SetPixel(x, y, RGB(r, g, b));

Comment: There is nothing really "simple" about accurate color adjustments.  In general, I've found the easiest way is to find a good library that does what you want and use it. Paul's suggestion of CBitmapEx is a good place to start.  If you really want to understand how to do it, you can review the library code if you are using an open source one.